# How to index a NetCDF file very quickly

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, netcdf

So I am trying to index a NetCDF file to get stream flow rate data in a certain grid cell. The NetCDF file I am using has the following characteristics:

```
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>
root group (NETCDF3_CLASSIC data model, file format NETCDF3):
CDI: Climate Data Interface version 1.6.4 (http://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdi)
Conventions: CF-1.4
dimensions(sizes): lon(3600), lat(1800), time(31)
variables(dimensions): float64 lon(lon), float64 lat(lat), float64 time(time), float32 dis(time,lat,lon)
```

I have 35+ years of this data and I am trying to get the data from an individual grid and create a time-series to compare it do a different model's forecasts. The code I am currently using to extract data from a grid cell is below.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

root_grp = Dataset(r'C:\Users\wadear\Desktop\ERAIland_daily_dis_198001.nc')
dis = root_grp.variables['dis']
lat = np.round(root_grp.variables['lat'][:], decimals=2).tolist()
lon = np.round(root_grp.variables['lon'][:], decimals=2).tolist()
time = root_grp.variables['time'].shape[0]

lat_index = lat.index(27.95)
lon_index = lon.index(83.55)

for i in range(time):
    print(dis[i][lat_index][lon_index])
```

Right now this feels really slow, and it will take a long time to do this over a 35+ year timespan, and while doing multiple different grid cells, the time it takes will really build up.

Is there a tool to speed up this process with faster I/O or indexing?

Thanks!

Comment: You should look into [tag:pandas]

Comment: Probably [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) is more suitable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get a big time saving if you remove the loop over time and access the entire time series at once, i.e.

```
dis[:,lat_index,lon_index]
```

Further speed gains can be obtained if you apply chunking in the time dimension. Look up the documentation for `nccopy`. If you need to access the time series repeatedly, this is worth doing. You may wish to concatenate some of your NetCDF files before chunking, e.g. monthly -> annual. This is done using `ncrcat` utility.

See also [Chunking Data: Why it Matters](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/blogs/developer/entry/chunking_data_why_it_matters).

Comment: Thanks for this, accessing the entire time series all at once save tons of time. I haven't yet merged all of the files, but I think I will do this soon to improve efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

why not simply extract the point with CDO first and then read in the point data:

```
cdo remapnn,lon=83.55/lat=27.95 input.nc point_output.nc
```

on ubuntu if you don't have CDO installed, you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install cdo
```